# For Loop for select the checked Radio Button

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

I've tried to take the value of the selected Radio Button through a for loop. Yes it works.

But if no Radio Button is selected I need to show up a message. for that I used a variable called flag. But that part doesn't work.

```
function selRadio()
{
    var i;
    var flag="no";

    for (i=0;i<=(document.form.ra.length);i++)
    {
        if (document.form.ra[i].checked)
        {
            alert(Number(i+1));
            flag="yes"; 
        }   
    }

    if (flag=="no")
    {
        alert("click on some Radio Button");
    }
}


<form name="form">

    <p>1 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="1"></p>

    <p>2 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="2"></p>

    <p>3 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="3"></p>

    <p>4 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="4"></p>

    <p>5 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="5"></p>

    <input type="button" value="Click" onClick='seRadio();'>

</form>
```

Comment: *correction onClick='selRadio();'

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selRadio()
{
    var i;
    var flag="no";

    for (i=0;i<=(document.form.ra.length);i++)
    {

        if (typeof document.form.ra[i] != 'undefined' && document.form.ra[i].checked)
        {
            alert(Number(i+1));
            flag="yes"; 
        }   
    }

    if (flag=="no")
    {
        alert("click on some Radio Button");
    }
}
</script>
<form name="form">

    <p>1 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="1"></p>

    <p>2 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="2"></p>

    <p>3 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="3"></p>

    <p>4 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="4"></p>

    <p>5 <input type="radio" name="ra" id="5"></p>

    <input type="button" value="Click" onClick="selRadio();">

</form>
```

In console, I was getting undefined element index, so checked for undefined condition. 
I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array elements from 0 to length-1, otherwise you run into an exception and the function `selRadio()` is terminated before checking `flag`:

```
for (i=0;i<(document.form.ra.length);i++)
{
    if (document.form.ra[i].checked)
    {
        alert(Number(i+1));
        flag="yes"; 
    }   
}
```

(replace `<=` with `<` in the loop condition)